# Installing a C# WPF application with local SQL Server database on another PC

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, publish

I have a question that I have developed a C# WPF application which requires a local SQL Server database. I am having trouble publishing the application to a different computer where there is no SQL Server installed.

Is it necessary for me to have a SQL Server installed on all the PCs where I am going to install my application? Or am I missing something?

I am making the setup file form Advance Installer and copying the `.mdf` database to the location mentioned in the connection string

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source =(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\abc\Databases\abc.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";
```

The error I am getting:

[image: error message]

If having a SQL Server a necessity, which one should I install on a low end pc? 
any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `.mdf` file, then you **must have** SQL Server installed

- either locally on each PC
- or centrally on a **server** which all the PC's can connect to

If you install a `.mdf` file locally on a PC and you want to use the `AttachDbFileName=` parameter in your connection string, then you **must install SQL Server Express** on each PC that has this application. Other editions of SQL Server **do NOT support** the `AttachDbFileName=` approach.

Comment: okay the answer is very clear thankyou, but what if i do not use the `.mdf` file? what are the other ways to achieve the goal?

Comment: @YasarKhalid: Not sure what you're asking - you *could* of course use a *different* database system - like SQLite or others - that do not require an installation of server components - but that means changing all your database code ...

Comment: thankyou for your solution, i am going for one local server, and i am going to use 1 central database for two systems over the LAN, but the (database or the server) is only allowing only one connection at a time, how to have two or more concurrent connections for one database? any help? @marc_s